# Looking to find Min and Max rows for various unsorted ranges in a column

Tags: excel

I have a unique problem that I'm not sure can be solved easily in a spreadsheet.

I have a list of unsorted values that create various data ranges.

| Values | Second Value | Desired Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Data A | 1 |
| Value 1 | Data A | 2 |
| Value 1 | Data A | 3 |
| Value 2 | Data B | 1 |
| Value 2 | Data B | 2 |
| Value 3 | Data C | 1 |
| Value 1 | Data A | 1 |
| Value 1 | Data A | 2 |
| Value 1 | Data A | 3 |
| Value 1 | Data A | 4 |
| Value 2 | Data B | 1 |
| Value 2 | Data B | 2 |
| Value 2 | Data B | 3 |

See the example spreadsheet below.  Thanks in advance for your help.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTwj4cb3Kn1H8FSC0pBkbsofifIA8IixmceIg_Idblh4JLFzXSKLMb6xp5yy8xMXDmRyHXt2S_87jJL/pubhtml)

SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIF seem to be close but not quite right.

The client has a file that has a static order. Since the column can not be sorted, it creates blocks of data ranges that contain a certain count of items.

Each time a new block starts, it should restart the number. Simply using a MIN and MAX do not work since there are multiple ranges of the same data spread throughout the column.

A block that repeats later in the file will simply continue in the numbered order using the last range's max value which is incorrect. Please look at the example data and the desired outcome and see if there are any remaining questions.

Notes:
I can not change the order so sorting is not an option.

Comment: Please include in the verbiage why just using MIN and MAX do not work.  You are assuming we know what you know about the data.  This question needs more specifics.

Comment: Not sure how much clearer I can be with the example given and the actual spreadsheet.

Comment: The file should not be the only place to contain the details.   You need to explain the why better each number exists where it does..

Comment: The client has a file that has a static order.  Since the column can not be sorted, it creates blocks of data ranges that contain a certain count of items.  Each time a new block starts, it should restart the number.  Simply using a MIN and MAX do not work since there are multiple ranges of the same data spread throughout the column.  A block that repeats later in the file will simply continue in the numbered order using the last range's max value which is incorrect.  Please look at the example data and the desired outcome and see if there are any remaining questions.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I have done it, but for future reference, clarification like the last comment should be [edit]ed into the question and not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple IF statement checking for changes will suffice here:

```
=IF(OR(B2<>B1,A2<>A1),1,C1+1)
```

Put that in C2 and copy down.  Now if either A or B change it starts the count back at `1` else it adds `1` to the number above.

[image]

---

With Office 365 one can use SCAN to do the same thing at once:

```
=SCAN(0,ROW(A2:A14),LAMBDA(z,y,IF(OR(INDEX(A:A,y-1)<>INDEX(A:A,y),INDEX(B:B,y-1)<>INDEX(B:B,y)),1,z+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Scott.  That will definitely work.  I think that's the simplest solution.  Was also curious if anyone has ever solved this using any type of ARRAYFORMULA.

Comment: Excel does not have the `ARRAYFORMULA` command, but in Office 365 Excel you can use SCAN: `=SCAN(0,ROW(A2:A14),LAMBDA(z,y,IF(OR(INDEX(A:A,y-1)<>INDEX(A:A,y),INDEX(B:B,y-1)<>INDEX(B:B,y)),1,z+1)))`

Comment: Scott, that is fantastic.  Excellent answer that I can use as an additional option.